# how to access the same values inside a list in Python 3 ex ["i",v","v","k","x","q"]

Tags: python, list

Can someone help me to solve the **python program** in the link below

**<https://hr.gs/70xk >**

> Given a string S of length N that is indexed from 0 to N-1, print its even-indexed and odd-indexed characters as 2 space-separated strings on a single line.

**my code to solve the problem is below**

```
def fun(x):
    fe = ''
    fo = ''

    if len(x) == 1:
        pass
    else :
        val = list(x)

        for i in val :

            if val.index(i) % 2 == 0:
                fe = fe + i
            else :
                fo = fo + i
        print(fe,fo)

for stdin in range(3):
    inputs = input("")
    fun(inputs)
```

but this has solved only **one case**  where the **input** are

```
2
Hacker
Rank
```

but for the **input below**

```
2
ivvkxq
ivvkx
```

the **output** I got was

```
ix vvkq
ix vvk
```

but the **expected output** was

```
ivx vkq
ivx vk
```

Comment: What does this have to do with `pip` or `windows`?

Comment: `index()` is not the right tool with this approach - consider using `for index, char in enumerate(string)`.

Comment: Sir can you please give any example for the enumerate(string) function it is the first time I am hearing this function

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this. It uses what ack mentioned. `enumerate()` gives you the index and value to separate variables.

```
def fun(x):
    fe = ''
    fo = ''
    val = list(x)

    for index, value in enumerate(val):
        if index % 2 == 0:
            fe = fe + value
        else :
            fo = fo + value
    
    print(fe,fo)

for stdin in range(3):
    inputs = input("")
    fun(inputs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach using SLICING:

```py
def fun(x):
    print(x[::2],x[1::2])
#         evens   odds

fun('ivvkxq') # ivx vkq
fun('ivvkx') # ivx vk
```